# Is there an "Approve" option on SU for edits made to my input?

Tags: discussion, editing

I have had a few edits done on some of my posts and that's fine, it has helped to fit in the SU site. But while on another StackExchange site, any edits give me the ability to Approve them. Is this not available in SU? Or is it Rep driven?

Not a real issue, just wondering :)

Edit: I should note that there was a discrepancy, in that an edit left out a part that I thought was needed. I put it back in. Thus the reason for this question.

Comment: Also, you basically have an approve button; use the 'rollback' option if you don't like the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular edits are immediate, and you only get a notification about those after they changed your post.

You can only approve (or decline) *suggested edits* by users who do not yet have the required [editing privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges/edit) to perform regular edits. These are placed in a queue for review by more experienced users, and only actually performed once approved.

---

So, yes, there is an *approve* button, but only when the editing user does not yet have at least 2000 reputation.

Comment: uhm...2000 reps correct? And I can't edit your answer, the edit is there but dim as in not accessible.

Comment: @CarlB suggested edits are not available on Meta

Comment: @Sathya But metahelp *is* made on Meta, so you can tell us where suggestions *are* made.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch I'm not sure I understand your question?

Comment: @Sathya Sorry, I misread your comment.

Comment: Maybe buttons should stay with all edits (Approve is no-op or slight upvote to the editor and Decline is rollback)?

Comment: @Vi. You get notified about edits in your inbox. You can rollback from the [post history](http://meta.superuser.com/posts/5541/revisions). Access it for any edited post by clicking the link in (in this case) *edited Sep 9 at 1:20*, and you can select *rollback* to any earlier revision.